# How to set newItem to JOptionPane?

Tags: java, ios, swing

```
public static InventoryItem addNewItem(){

    InventoryItem newItem;
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Enter new product name.",
                    " by Marquis Watkins", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) 
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Enter product price." ,
                    " by Marquis Watkins", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter quantity of product.",
                    " by Marquis Watkins", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    return newItem;
}
```

This method gets three inputs from the user using `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()`

And then uses the values entered to construct a new InventoryItem object and returns to the caller and object reference to that new InventoryItem.

About 10-12 lines.How do I set newItem to return my `JOptionPane` input screen?

Comment: `showInputDialog()` returns a `String`, which is what the user typed in. Currently you are discarding those values. Also you are not constructing `newItem` anywhere.

Comment: So i shouldnt use showInputDialog()?

Comment: You can, the problem is that you are not storing the value which it returns.

Comment: @JoeSmith `String productName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter new product name."," by Marquis            Watkins", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);`, then you need to assign the resulting value to your `newItem` some how

Comment: Thanks bro Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the code for `InventoryItem` we can't know, but something like this should get you on the right track. As mentioned in the comment by @Cinnam, you need to store the return values:

```
public static InventoryItem addNewItem() {

    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Enter new product name."," by Marquis Watkins", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    String price = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Enter product price." ," by Marquis  Watkins", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    String quantity = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter quantity of product."," by Marquis Watkins", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    return new InventoryItem(name, price, quantity);
}
```

Here I assumed that you can construct an `InventoryItem` from the 3 strings.

Comment: Thanks i made the class for InventoryItem and those are the variables i used

Comment: @JoeSmith If this answered your question, consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer (green checkmark).

Comment: Not sure because it didnt run how i expected

Comment: @JoeSmith Understood, but that's out of the scope of the question you posted.

Comment: If you have a different problem with your code that you can't find an answer for then ask a new question with the relevant code?